# Is it true that Empress Elisabeth of Austria did math?

Tags: mathematics, debunking, 19th-century

I have encountered a user on Math Stack Exchange with [writing in his bio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/698573/erik-satie) that [Empress Elisabeth of Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Elisabeth_of_Austria) ("Sisi") did some math and she was famous for an unsolvable integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{si}(x)\operatorname{si}(x)\;\text{d}x$$

I am unsure if this is the precise integral that I saw in his bio. Anyways, I have did google searches and didn't find anything about her as a mathematician. I hope someone can provide any historical context.

Comment: I suggest, you ask that user (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/698573/erik-satie). This can be done, for instance, by asking the same question at MSE and pinging him (I assume, that's he). My guess is that the claim is just a joke (SiSi).

Comment: Great, now I need to dig up my copy of  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik  to see if this is listed there :-)

Comment: This is the funniest question I ever encountered here.

Comment: Empress Elisabeth is called Sisi. The formula we see contains "Si" two times. This smacks of the Italian specialist mathematician: Signor Alessandro Binomi, who is only known for his biggest feat: he invented the [Binomial (polynomial)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_(polynomial))? Of [Mr Binomi, we know the following:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomi) "One of the first uses in a mathematical textbook is as "Alessandro Binomi" in the mathematical study standard work of Otto Forster, Analysis 1 (Vieweg Verlag, Braunschweig), from the year 1976. [cont.]

Comment: [continuation of LangLangC's comment, originally posted as an answer] There it is entered in the name register. As Binomi's life data the data of Sir Isaac Newton were taken and exchanged (* 1727, † 1643).

More than 30 years later, in the Bavarian edition of Lambacher Schweizer 9 (a mathematics book from the Klett publishing house) published in 2007, the figure reappears on page 24 as "Francesco Binomi" together with a picture by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, with 1472 to 1483, i.e. only eleven years, given as life data. [cont.]

Comment: In this context, the students are also asked to research the origin of the word Binom. It also appeared in the Baden-Württemberg and Rhineland-Palatinate editions of "Lambacher Schweizer 8"."

Comment: @Danu That's strange: usually, users are strongly encouraged to use the answer-box, not comments? It was already too long for a comment. Given that this is circumstantial evidence: what's needed now to re-instate the answer? I could add some bio of Sisi that indicates her lack of and disdain for formal math training? The absolute absence of any hint of the above anywhere else? The jocular nature of the Math-users bio, or of the formula's content?

Comment: The targeting of an individual on this site is entirely inappropriate as was tagging them on a question they asked.  You should just ask a question and leave individuals out of this.

Comment: @LаngLаngС People are only discouraged from posting comments if they are answering the question. In this case, I don't think your post really tried to answer the question, so I didn't think it appropriate to be posted as such. You're right though that this is something of a borderline case; I think that if you had added an explicit statement saying something along the lines of "this is likely a joke, Empress Elisabeth did not do any mathematics", I would've left it. So if you're willing, feel free to add this to your original answer and repost! I can then delete the comments (if you flag).

Answer (score 4):

She didn't do any math. From my research about her, it seems that the user you are referring to is teasing the fact that her nickname was "Sisi" which looks similar to the integrand. I also highly doubt the integral of the cardinal sine function was even denoted at the time (the earliest mention of it I can find is by Abramowitz in the 1980s, although I'm sure it existed maybe a few decades before). The only sign of education I've found about her (citing Wikipedia page, couldn't find enough information elsewhere) was mostly learning languages while getting her hair groomed.

As a fun note, the dictator of Egypt is named "Abdelfattah El-Sisi" so I guess he did/does math as well.